# Android Studio XML context error

Tags: android, xml, parse-platform

Hi I'm following this Simple Parse Messaging App tutorial-https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Building-Simple-Chat-Client-with-Parse
And I'm getting an error on this line of code:

```
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}"
```

This is the whole file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etMessage"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btSend"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btSend"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:hint="contribute..."
    android:imeOptions="actionSend"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btSend"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="send"
    android:textSize="18sp" >
</Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `${relativePackage}` with your package name and replace `${activityClass}` with your class name.

For example:

```
tools:context="whatever.your.package.name.ChatActivity"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the tutorial means you should populate `relativePackage` and `activityClass` yourself. `tools:context` must refer to a specific `Activity`, e.g. `com.example.MainActivity`.